# Is there clang documentation for warnings by clang version?

Tags: clang

I would like to find out on which clang version were certain warnings/diagnostics added.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check the history of the [docs/DiagnosticGroups.rst](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticGroups.td) file for changes from one release to another.

**UPD** as DiagnosticGroups (previously DiagnosticReference) was introduced only in 2016, previous releases are not *reachable* with this approach. In order to get the history of each warning the other way, one must parse all *include/clang/Basic/Diagnostic*Kinds.td* and search for **Warning** declarations and track their history. [LLVM TableGen documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/TableGen/index.html) might be of good use here.

I hope this information is useful!

Comment: Unfortunately the reference wasn't there before 4.0

Comment: File has moved to https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticGroups.td, updated link above accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The github repo [pkolbus/compiler-warnings](https://github.com/pkolbus/compiler-warnings) has a per-version list of warnings for [clang](https://github.com/pkolbus/compiler-warnings/blob/main/clang/README.md), [gcc](https://github.com/pkolbus/compiler-warnings/blob/main/gcc/README.md) and [Apple clang](https://github.com/pkolbus/compiler-warnings/blob/main/xcode/README.md), which seems reasonably up to date.